# Why is there a crown on my head?

Tags: beat-stomper

Sometimes while playing Beat Stomper, I'll see a small white crown appear on my character's head.

Once the crown appears, it stays on my character's head until I die or start a new round.

[image: small white crown]

What is this white crown? What makes it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white crown appears when you have beaten your previous high score. ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/iosgaming/comments/6h29y2/comment/div2ppu?st=J7GBIAX4&sh=f8d0b4fb))

You can view your high score above your most recent score on the title screen before starting a round.

[image: High score on title screen]